# Lookup field missing from matching rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Wanted to have a have a matching rule where if a combination of fields already exist throw a warning.
So there are 3 fields in the rule.
Text field and Picklist are visible but the lookup is not.
I can see a another lookup value in the list but not the one i need?
This is a lookup and n ot a master detail.
Any suggestions is appreciated.
Thanks,
P

Comment: Is this on a standard object or a custom object? Is the lookup a custom field?

Comment: Hey Kris,  
The object and lookup are both custom.  I can see other lookups in the Matching Rule list but just not the one I need. 
Thx